# How to define a peicewise function in a function file - Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

I made a funnction file and defined a peicewise function inside it using conditionals and a for loop. I tried calling the function in a seperate m.file but the variables 't' and 'v' aren't showing in the workspace, rather it is just outputting a vector with the t values called 'ans.

I tried putting the exact code (without the function definition) into a regular m file and it worked just fine showing both variables t and v

```
    #function file
function [t, v] = VPieceWise(t_start, t_end);
t = t_start:0.01:t_end;
for i = 1:length(t);
    if (t(i) >= 0) && (t(i) <= 10);
        v(i) = 11.*(t(i).^2) - (5.*t(i));
    elseif (t(i) >= 10) && (t(i) <= 20);
        v(i) = 1100 - 5.*t(i);
    elseif (t(i) >= 20) && (t(i) <= 30);
        v(i) = 50.*t(i) + 2*((t(i)-20).^2.5);
    elseif (t(i) >= 30) && (t(i) <= 100);
        v(i) = 1520.*exp(-0.1.*(t(i)-30));
    elseif (t(i) >= -100) && (t(i) <= 0);
        v(i) = 0;
    end
end
end
#m file
clear all; clc; close all
t_start = input('enter the start time');
t_end = input('enter the end time');
VPieceWise(t_start,t_end)
plot(t,v)
```

Comment: Have a look at [Scripts vs. Functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html). You have to call your function like `[t, v] = VPieceWise(t_start, t_end)`. Just calling `VPieceWise(t_start, t_end)` results in putting the content of the first return value (it's `t` in your case) to the "standard return value" of the workspace `ans`.

Comment: Imagine the mess you’d get if the function M-file determined the name of the variables you get when you call the function. What if two M-files you need happen to create the same variable, overwriting each other’s result? What if you need to call one function twice with different inputs and combine the results? It certainly makes sense for the variables inside the function to be local variables, and for the caller to decide for herself what variable to assign the function’s output to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function has two outputs, you should also assign them when calling the function. If you do not do that, only the first output will be put in the `ans` variable.

So call your function as follows:

```
clear all; clc; close all
t_start = input('enter the start time');
t_end = input('enter the end time');
[t,v] = VPieceWise(t_start,t_end);
plot(t,v)
```